# Magento 2 : How to update customer password by customer repository

Tags: magento2, customer, password

I want update customer password by customer repository.

Currently I am updating customer password like this

```
$this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface
    ->save($customer,$this->encryptor->getHash($password, true));
```

> \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository

but it is not working for me.

Any one know how to update customer password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have completed by below code

private $encryptor;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor $encryptor,
)
{
    $this->_customerRegistry   = $customerRegistry;
    $this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepository;
    $this->encryptor = $encryptor;

}
```

Use below code in my custom function for update customer data

```
$customer = $this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface->getById($id);
$customerSecure = $this->_customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
$customerSecure->setRpToken(null);
$customerSecure->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
$customerSecure->setPasswordHash($this->encryptor->getHash($password, true));
$this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
```

**Or Update customer passward by Email:**

```
 $password="M@123456";
 $customer = $this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface->get($email, $websiteId);
 $this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface->save($customer, $this->encryptor->getHash($password, true));
```

Comment: What we need to pass in $id for this first line?    $customer = $this->_CustomerRepositoryInterface->getById($id);

Comment: need to pass customer id?

Comment: $this->encryptor->getHash($password, true) show error